# Can an Android app detect its previous crashes itself?

Tags: android

Is it possible for an Android app to be notified that it was crashed?

My app has a service, and sometimes it might be crashed. I'd like to be notified about that immediately or when the service is started again for collecting debug information and making a report.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize Google Firebase for this purpose. It will notify the crashes immediately in the Firebase crashlytics console.

Answer (score 1):

No, the app itself cannot detect that it crashed. You can possibly use services such as Firebase Crashlytics and Firebase Cloud Messaging to tell the app that it crashed, but this doesn't seem like the right solution. You should just use Firebase Crashlytics to monitor crashes and then fix the root cause of the problem and deploy an update.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to register your own `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` using

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()
```

I recommend checking [the source code](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/blob/5bf8dd77f81ee943e2123fe28ce5b3a36853ef8e/acra-core/src/main/java/org/acra/reporter/ErrorReporterImpl.kt#L163) of ACRA - an open-source library to integrate crash reporting.

Comment: This will only catch some crashes.  There are classes of bugs which it can't catch- ANRs, anything that crashes the VM itself (segfaults for example), reentrant crashes may not be caught by that.  It can work, but its not 100%.  And you'd need to call that on every thread you create, including those created by libraries (which is basically impossible).  Which is why ACRA only ever sort of worked.